# Epsilon-delta proof with $x$ and $y$ defined

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am stuck with the following problem. The question is as follows: prove that for all $x$ in $[0,2]$, there exists $y$ in $[0,2]$ such that the function $f(x,y)=0$. The function $f$ is defined as $f(x,y)=x+y^3+y-3$.

I thought about writing an epsilon-delta proof, but I couldn't. Or mean value theorem might work, but I really could not proceed from this initial thoughts.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An epsilon-delta proof is usually used to prove limits. You aren't taking a limit, so you probably don't want to do that. Thinking about the mean value theorem is a little bit closer, but we'll use the intermediate value theorem.

First, note that $f(x,y) = y^3 + y - x$ is a continuous function. Fixing $x \in [0,2]$, we might think of this as a one variable continuous function $f(y) = y^3 + y - x$. Note that $f(0) = -x < 0$ and $f(2) = 8 + 2 - x = 10 - x > 0$. So the intermediate value theorem guarantees that there is a $y$ such that $f(y) = 0$.

Comment: Brief note:  you need to handle the case $x=0$ seperately,  but that's a trivial one to find the explicit y.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g:[0,2]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $g(y)=y^3+y-3$.  $[-2,0]$ is a subset of the range of g.  Therefore, for any value of $x$ in $[0,2]$ there exists a $y$ such that $f(x,y)=0$.